# c++ condition_variable wait_for predicate in my class, std::thread <unresolved overloaded function type> error

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I am trying to use a thread within my class, then the thread needs to use a `condition_variable`, and the condition variable will be blocked until a predicate be changed to `true`. The code looks like this:

```
class myThreadClass{
    bool bFlag;
    thread t ;
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cv;

    bool myPredicate(){
      return bFlag;
    }

    int myThreadFunction(int arg){
       while(true){
           unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
           if(cv.wait_for(lck,std::chrono::milliseconds(3000),myPredicate)) //something wrong?  
                cout<<"print something...1"<<endl 
           else
                cout<<"print something...2"<<endl 
       }
    }

    void createThread(){
        t = thread(&myThreadClass::myThreadFunction,this,10);//this is ok
    }

} ;
```

This code on compilation throws an error saying:

> unresolved overloaded function type in the line “wait_for”.

Then i try modify it to:

```
if(cv.wait_for(lck,std::chrono::milliseconds(3000),&myThreadClass::myPredicate))
```

But there is still an error.

Comment: `if (cv.wait_for(lck, std::chrono::milliseconds(3000), [this]{ return myPredicate(); }))`

Comment: Use of predicate is wrong. That is how predicate can't be used.

Answer (score 6):

The predicate needs to be callable without any context.  You are trying to invoke this on a non-static class member, which requires an object on which to operate.

You can use a lambda function to capture the object's context and wrap the function call into a suitable type:

```
const std::chrono::milliseconds timeout( 3000 );
if( cv.wait_for( lck, timeout, [this]{ return myPredicate(); } ) )
    // ...
```

If you only created `myPredicate` because of the condition variable, you can do away with it and just use this:

```
if( cv.wait_for( lck, timeout, [this]{ return bFlag; } ) )
```

Answer (score 4):

A (pointer to a) member function as a **predicate** isn't suitable, since it requires an object to be called on, so you'll need a wrapper to bind the member function to an object and make it callable with just the two values to compare.

In C++11, you can bind a member function to an object:

```
class myThreadClass{

bool bFlag;
thread t ;
mutex mtx;
condition_variable cv;

bool myPredicate(){
  return bFlag;
}

int myThreadFunction(int arg){
   while(true){
       unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
       if(cv.wait_for(lck,std::chrono::milliseconds(3000),std::bind(&myThreadClass::myPredicate,this))) //something wrong?  
            cout<<"print something...1"<<endl; 
       else
            cout<<"print something...2"<<endl; 
   }
}

void createThread(){
    t = thread(&myThreadClass::myThreadFunction,this,10);//this is ok
}
};
```

you can use placeholders in bind.

Or you can use lambda functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in fact the best way to do this is..

```
auto myPredicate = [this]{ return bFlag; }
```

and then using

```
if (cv.wait_for(lck, std::chrono::milliseconds(3000), myPredicate))
```

This way you can eliminate the `myPrediate` method.